# What is a fast an elegant way to transform a column with a bunch a duplicated, without running the transformation on the same value multiple times

Tags: python, pandas

Lets assume we have a pandas data frame `df` with the column `'A'`, and the following non-vectorized transformation function:

```py
def transform_a_to_b(a):
    ...
    return b
```

Then if we wanted to create the column `'B'` using the transform on `'A'`, we could do the following:

```py
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: transform_a_to_b(a))
```

What is a better way to do this if the transform takes a non-trivial amount of time, there are many duplicate values in the column `'A'`, and the transform always maps the duplicate a values to the same b value? Also assume there are more columns in the data frame so I do want to map the values back to every single row in the original data frame.

I came up with the following solution, but I feel like something simpler should exist.

```py
transform_counts = 0
def transform_a_to_b(a):
    global transform_counts
    # Keep count of how many times this was called
    transform_counts += 1

    return 2 * a

# Test dataframe with several duplicates
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
})

# My solution:
# Perform transformation only 3 times for the 3 unique A values and preserve order
df = df.merge(
    df['A'].drop_duplicates().apply(lambda a: pd.Series(
        data=[a, transform_a_to_b(a)],
        index=['A', 'B'],
    )),
    on='A',
    how='left',
)
```

After the function `transform_counts` is `3` and the df is as follows:

```
    A  B
0   1  2
1   3  6
2   2  4
3   2  4
4   3  6
5   3  6
6   2  4
7   3  6
8   1  2
9   1  2
10  1  2
```

I am not apposed to caching, if that is simplest, but I cannot change the original transformation definition.

Comment: @Tiago that's missing the point of the question. This is just a dummy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good, I would just use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)+[`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) in place of `merge`+`drop_duplicates`.

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map({k: transform_a_to_b(k) for k in df['A'].unique()})
```

A pythonic alternative would be to. [`cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) your function:

```
from functools import cache

transform_counts = 0

@cache
def transform_a_to_b(a):
    global transform_counts
    # Keep count of how many times this was called
    transform_counts += 1
    return 2 * a

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
})

df['B'] = df['A'].map(transform_a_to_b)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0   1  2
1   3  6
2   2  4
3   2  4
4   3  6
5   3  6
6   2  4
7   3  6
8   1  2
9   1  2
10  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I like the idea of caching, but I am unable to edit the file where the transformations come from. Should I just wrap the function to cache it? or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Yes, you can just wrap the function in your own code: `cached_func = cache(original_func)` then use `cached_func`. Or without name: `df['B'] = df['A'].map(cache(transform_a_to_b))`

Comment: @mozway Can I wrap lambda functions into cache to enhance its performance? something like `cache(lambda x: x*2)`

Comment: Yes you can, you need to make sure to reuse it though, not to recreate it every time ;)